# set cookie in jquery for show/hide

Tags: javascript

This is my cods: 
i want a cookie for this for remember user preference in cookie 
 please help me
thanks

```js
function showhide(id){
if (document.getElementById){
obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display == "none"){
obj.style.display = "";
} else {
obj.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('script'); return(false);">show/hide</a>


<div style="display: none;" id="script"> 
this cantent is show or hide
</div>
```

Comment: Here's a good resouce: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/tree/v1.4.1). In this page there are a lot of examples of how to set and get cookies.

Also, you can use the [html5 local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), that i think it's better.

To "remember" the state when the window is open, you can trigger your `showhide` function, with the stored data as id. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //get the ids from cookie or localStorage
    //call the showHide function for each id
});
```

Comment: thank you for Guidance but i cant please do it For the learning for me (thank you very much)

Comment: You are getting any error? Post what you've done, then we can help you.

Comment: thank you but i am not Programmer just i want a java script cod for remember in cookie plugin for this script if you can help me???thank you very much

Comment: hi dis is my cod but not save show and hide content please help me